# convert pkl file into columns rather than a list

Tags: python

I have a pkl file that when i open it up using pd.read_pickle the data is shown as a list, example below:

```
[{'text': 'what is your favorite song ? d i like too many songs to have a favorite',
  'label': 0},
 {'text': '3 3 ? haha jk ! 33', 'label': 0},
 {'text': 'hey angel you duh sexy really ? ! ? ! thanks ? ! haha', 'label': 0},
 {'text': '', 'label': 0},
 {'text': 'meowww rawr ?', 'label': 0},
```

I really want to use the specific dataset to conduct a sentiment analysis but i honestly dont know how to convert the pkl file into a dataframe, were the columns are text and label and show the text with the corresponding label on each row.

Answer (score 0):

I suspect the pkl file is not originally generated using [DataFrame.to_pickle](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.to_pickle.html#pandas.DataFrame.to_pickle) so it cannot be unpicked into a data frame using pd.read_pickle.

How I would do it, is to put the list into a pandas DataFrame using [from_records](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.from_records.html#pandas.DataFrame.from_records), for example:

```
import pandas as pd
user_data=[{'text': 'what is your favorite song ? d i like too many songs to have a favorite',
  'label': 0},
 {'text': '3 3 ? haha jk ! 33', 'label': 0},
 {'text': 'hey angel you duh sexy really ? ! ? ! thanks ? ! haha', 'label': 0},
 {'text': '', 'label': 0},
 {'text': 'meowww rawr ?', 'label': 0},]
user_df = pd.DataFrame.from_records(data=user_data)
```